# CSProj Conditionals for different DLLs triggered by build configurations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, x86, 64-bit

I'm attempting to modify my `.csproj` files to handle some native and (managed) wrapper assemblies based upon the targeted build configuration (specifically `$(Platform)`). A specific example (though not the only one) is I'm using `Oracle.DataAccess` which comes mutually exclusively targeting 32-bit or 64-bit, but not both. Additionally, it has dependencies on 32-bit and 64-bit (respectively) native DLLs. This example creates a problem for me. The reason I want this triggered based on the build configuration is because we are frequently having to switch back and forth for a variety of reasons.

**Problem:**
I include the native DLLs by having them in a project's root directory (**as a linked file** pointing to a `lib` folder), flagging them as `Content` with `AlwaysCopy` set. This results in them being copied to my `bin` folder as desired. I attempted to do this by having two `ItemGroup` blocks with `Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'"` (and `x64`) but this seems to not work as I get build errors saying "The file ..\packages\OracleClient\64BitNativeDrivers\xxx.dll' could not be added to the project. There is already a file of the same name in this folder.", even after a very thorough cleaning of the solution's artifacts.

Code snippet:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
    <Content Include="..\packages\OracleClient\32BitNativeDrivers\oci.dll">
      <Link>oci.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\packages\OracleClient\32BitNativeDrivers\oraociicus11.dll">
      <Link>oraociicus11.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\packages\OracleClient\32BitNativeDrivers\OraOps11w.dll">
      <Link>OraOps11w.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
    <Content Include="..\packages\OracleClient\64BitNativeDrivers\oci.dll">
      <Link>oci.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\packages\OracleClient\64BitNativeDrivers\oraociicus11.dll">
      <Link>oraociicus11.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\packages\OracleClient\64BitNativeDrivers\OraOps11w.dll">
      <Link>OraOps11w.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I've tried playing around with a few possibilities here but it seems I'm misunderstanding how to do this properly and I could really use some help.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not just copy them in a Post-build event?  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20525019/17034) for example

Comment: Great question! This is somewhat problematic for Intellisense in some scenarios. Doing it the way I'm trying to do it keeps Intellisense happy at all times. Also, doing it this way allows it to be "reconsumable" by other projects that have a project reference to this one. With post-build copies, things get trickier there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try putting the filter

```
Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'"
```

on the `<Content>` tag ?

Comment: PS.  I'm not sure how you create the deployment artifacts, but I would zip up the 2 separate version of the Oracle dlls.  So everything you needed (minus the oracle files) was in one zip, and then 2 separate zips for the 32 vs 64 bit oracle packages, and then the final product would be the first zip plus one of the two oracle zips.  You might have a much more robust deployment package (.msi), but just making a note here for future readers.

Comment: Wow, that did it! Would you mind explaining to me why this works but the filter on the `ItemGroup` does not work?

Comment: I don't know.  Why is the sky blue?  Why does a cow go moo?  I fought the Oracle 32 vs 64 w@r before.  And that's what I came up with.  I'm just thankful you can specify non-TNS connection strings with the ODP.NET.  Actually, I'm more thankful I left the Oracle job and am back with Sql Server.  Anyway.  Glad it worked.

Comment: Hah, I wish I could change to SQL Server here. Federal gov't stuff doesn't make things easy. :-(